# Is there a workaround for "stack level too deep" errors in recursive routines?

Tags: ruby, recursion, stack-overflow, tail-call-optimization

Is there any workaround for Stack Overflow errors in recursive functions in Ruby?

Say, for example, I have this block:

```
def countUpTo(current, final)
    puts current
    return nil if current == final
    countUpTo(current+1, final)
end
```

if I call `countUpTo(1, 10000)`, I get an error: `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`.

It appears to break at 8187. Is there some function that I can call telling Ruby to ignore the size of stacks, or a way to increase the maximum stack size?

Comment: Ruby uses the C stack, so you can use something like [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) to adjust the limit on the stack depth.

Comment: Don't do this. If you're intentionally recusing 10,000 times, you're doing it horribly wrong and abusing recursion.

Comment: Ruby implementations don't necessarily do tail call elimination, so you're relying on using the C stack size. One possibility is that you could rewrite your function to be iterative.

Comment: Firstly, my own experience with Ruby is that it's not particularly good with recursion, in that it produces errors like this quite easily and it's slow(er than you'd like). Also, to get better performance in this area you need to compile Ruby with a certain constant set, but I didn't find this helped much at all. In other words, write your function differently using the usual Ruby methods like `times`, `upto` etc. @meagar unless you know what the goal is, I don't think you can make that assertion. I written methods in Haskell that recurse that number of times no problem and it's de rigeur.

Comment: Bully for Haskell, I don't see that as particularly relevant here?

Comment: I would not do this on any normal basis, but I'm trying to work through some previously solved Project Euler problems in Ruby to get a feel for the language. There are some pretty gigantic numbers there, and it's not always bad practice to have a huge stack under some circumstances that actual applications will never see. That said, I can try to work around these issues given Ruby's limitations. Might be a good exercise. Anyway, thanks for the responses, everyone.

Comment: @meagar The fact is there are plenty of reasons to recurse however many times it is required, in a functional language. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language) - "Ruby supports multiple programming paradigms, including *functional*, object oriented, imperative and reflective." That Ruby doesn't actually perform well with recursion is something you'd only realise through use, but in _theory_ it is a perfectly reasonable approach toward _any_ programming problem. The number of recursions is the true irrelevence.

Comment: So "in theory" it's great to recurse as much as you want, and then in the next breath tell me that "Ruby doesn't actually perform well with recursion". Your theory is wonderful. Menanwhile, we are dealing with a real code snippet written in a real language which is *really broken*, and it is because of rampant misuse of recursion.

Comment: @meagar: Then when should recursion be used?

Comment: @meagar Your phrase `Don't do this. If you're intentionally recusing 10,000 times, you're doing it horribly wrong and abusing recursion` is totally wrong. It is true only in case if language implementation has no tail call support.

Comment: @ArtemIce This is not a language-agnostic question. It is specifically about Ruby. Read the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using YARV (the C based implementation of Ruby 1.9), you can tell the Ruby VM to turn tail call optimization on:

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  :tailcall_optimization => true,
  :trace_instruction => false
}

def countUpTo(current, final)
    puts current
    return nil if current == final
    countUpTo(current+1, final)
end

countUpTo(1, 10_000)
```

Comment: As I wrote above, I found this to be of little impact, but YMMV.

Comment: After you set the compile_option, you can use `new` or `compile` methods on the instruction sequence, e.g.: `RubyVM::InstructionSequence.new('def meth_name(b,c); d = b + c; puts "#{b} + #{c} = #{d}. now doing #{b+1} + #{c}..."; meth_name(b+1, c) end').eval`. A more generic way of doing it is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/rogerleite/5101751).

Comment: Or if you'd rather not set options for everything, you can pass the options into compile/new, e.g. `RubyVM::InstructionSequence.new('def meth_name(b,c); d = b + c; puts "#{b} + #{c} = #{d}. now doing #{b+1} + #{c}..."; meth_name(b+1, c) end', nil, nil, nil, tailcall_optimization: true, trace_instruction: false).eval`. See [::RubyVM::InstructionSequence](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your snippet not to be recursive:

```
# 'count_up_to' would be a more "Ruby" name ;-)
def countUpTo(current, final)
  (current..final).each { |i| puts i }
end
```

I appreciate your code is probably an abstraction of what you're really trying to do, but it might help to form your solution if you think of other ways to iterate rather than recursively.

HTH

Comment: In general, unbounded recursion is bad. Most recursion can be rewritten to be iterative as Pavling has shownn.

Comment: @Pavling: Because you're saying "don't do it" (don't do recursion) without giving a valid reason not to do it.

Comment: I didn't say "don't do it". He's having problems with overflowing, and I suggested an alternative that would achieve the result without it :-/

Comment: @Pavling: I was afraid that the OP would get the impression that you can't do tail-end recursion in YARV Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 2.0 you can specify the stack size (in bytes) using [RUBY_THREAD_VM_STACK_SIZE](http://magazine.rubyist.net/?Ruby200SpecialEn-note#l16) and other environment variables.