# Ruby profiler stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby, profiler, ruby-prof

It seems like I always get this error on one of my scripts:

```
/Users/amosng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-prof-0.11.2/lib/ruby-prof/profile.rb:25: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Has anyone encountered this error before? What could be causing it, and what can I be doing to prevent it from happening?

I run my ruby-prof scripts using the command

```
ruby-prof --printer=graph --file=profile.txt scraper.rb -- "fall 2012"
```

**Edit** I'm on Mac OS X, if that matters. Doing `ulimit -s 64000` doesn't seem to help much, unfortunately. Here is what `ulimit -a` gives:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 64000
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

**Edit 2**

Andrew Grimm's solution worked just fine to prevent ruby-prof from crashing, but the profiler seems to have problems of its own, because I see percentages like 679.50% of total time taken for a process...

Comment: Have you tried [turning tail call optimization on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8735003/38765)?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yes, that worked! Thanks!! I'll accept it if you enter it in as an answer

Comment: Solving the more than 100% percentages problem probably merits its own question. You're not the first person to have such an issue. I'm not sure what the culprit is though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround would be to [turn tail call optimization on](http://ephoz.posterous.com/ruby-and-recursion-whats-up-in-19).

The following is an example of something that works with TCO on, but doesn't work when TCO is off.

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  :tailcall_optimization => true,
  :trace_instruction => false
}

def countUpTo(current, final)
  puts current
  return nil if current == final
  countUpTo(current+1, final)
end

countUpTo(1, 10_000)
```

Comment: Link is dead: "Posterous spaces is no longer available"

Answer (score 3):

Stack level too deep usually means an infinite loop. If you look at the [ruby-prof code where the error happens](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof/blob/master/lib/ruby-prof/profile.rb#L25) you will see that it's a method that detects recursion in the call stack.

Try looking into the code where you are using recursion (how many places in your code can you be using recursion?) and see if there is a condition that would cause it to never bottom-out?

It could also mean that your system stack just isn't big enough to handle what you are trying to do. Maybe you are processing a large data set recursively? You can check your stack size (unixy systems):

`$ ulimit -a`

and [increase the stack size](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/5-ruby-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror):

`$ ulimit -s 16384`

You can also consider adjusting your algorithm. [See this stack overflow quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242617/how-to-increase-stack-size-for-a-ruby-app-recursive-app-getting-stack-level-to)

I hope I'm not just re-hashing an existing question...

Comment: Well, my code works totally fine without the profiler, so I'm pretty sure it doesn't have any infinite loops. I did see the ulimit suggestion when Googling earlier, but when I execute `ulimit`, I get "unlimited" -- is this misleading?

Comment: Also, I don't see a stack trace when the program crashes -- just that one message. And it crashes when my programs ends -- I suspect that the program runs fine, but the profiler crashes after the program ends.

Comment: really? unlimited stack size? or are you looking at something else? `stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192`

Comment: What's happening is you script ends and then the profiler is processing the call stack. So it's probably just hitting the stack limit. Upping your stack size is probably the ticket.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, if that makes a difference. Probably does. Typing `ulimit 1000000` gives me `-bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted`

Comment: somehow you're missing the parameters e.g. `-a` and `-s` refer to my answer again. Also, why not set your stack size to something sane?

Comment: I mean, I thought `ulimit` by itself gives the current stack limit. I'll try setting the stack size to something a bit smaller, haha.

Comment: I did `ulimit -s 64000` but it still gives the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Having percentages go over 100% in Ruby-prof has been [a known bug](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof/issues/84), but should be fixed now.